# Building prestashop using docker-compose Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prestashop

I am trying to up prestashop in a docker container on an AWS EC2 instance. I use the latest `docker-compose.yml` file from [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml)

```
.....
      - "80:80"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
    enter code here
.....
```

but when starting the container I get this error:

```
prestashop-git_1  | ~/html/admin-dev/themes/default ~/html
prestashop-git_1  | npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
prestashop-git_1  | npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default
prestashop-git_1  | npm WARN default@1.7.5 No description
prestashop-git_1  | npm WARN default@1.7.5 No repository field.
prestashop-git_1  | 
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! code EACCES
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! syscall access
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! path /var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! errno -13
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default'
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default'] {
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!   errno: -13,
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!   path: '/var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default'
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! }
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! 
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! 
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
prestashop-git_1  | 
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
prestashop-git_1  | npm ERR!     /var/www/.npm/_logs/2022-01-15T21_02_42_638Z-debug.log
prestashop-git_1  | make: *** [Makefile:7: assets] Error 243
prestashop-git_1  | 
prestashop-git_1  | * Checking if mysql is available...
```

I tried to add `user: root` to `docker-compose.yml` to make sure there is no permissions issue, but it still fails.

I cloned the whole `Prestashop` repo:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-236 PrestaShop]$ ls 
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  admin-dev      composer.lock       images.inc.php  mails              tests         vendor
CONTRIBUTING.md     app            config              img             modules            tests-legacy  webservice
CONTRIBUTORS.md     autoload.php   controllers         index.php       override           themes
INSTALL.txt         bin            docker-compose.yml  init.php        pdf                tools
LICENSE.md          cache          docs                install-dev     phpstan.neon.dist  translations
Makefile            classes        download            js              src                upload
README.md           composer.json  error500.html       localization    templates          var
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-236 PrestaShop]$ ls admin-dev/
ajax_products_list.php  bootstrap.php            export          functions.php       import     robots.txt
autoupgrade             cron_currency_rates.php  favicon.ico     get-file-admin.php  index.php  searchcron.php
backup.php              displayImage.php         filemanager     grider.php          init.php   themes
backups                 drawer.php               footer.inc.php  header.inc.php      pdf.php
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-236 PrestaShop]$
```

Comment: Did you clone the whole repo or just grab the compose file?  Can we see what is the output of `ls -ld admin-dev/themes/default` run from the same directory?

Comment: @kthompso I cloned the whole git repo.  I updated the question with the required listings